# Difference between cleaned_data and cleaned_data.get in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've seen some samples codes like:

```
def clean_message(self):
    message = self.cleaned_data['message']
    num_words = len(message.split())
    if num_words < 4:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
    return message
```

and some examples like:

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    ...
    self.check_for_test_cookie()
    return self.cleaned_data
```

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: exactly the question (and answer) I needed. I hadn't run into using dictionary.get() since for all my development I'd always used the shortcut dictionary[key]

Answer (score 32):

[`.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is basically a shortcut for getting an element out of a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  I usually use `.get()` when I'm not certain if the entry in the dictionary will be there.  For example:

```
>>> cleaned_data = {'username': "bob", 'password': "secret"}
>>> cleaned_data['username']
'bob'
>>> cleaned_data.get('username')
'bob'
>>> cleaned_data['foo']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    KeyError: 'foo'
>>> cleaned_data.get('foo')  # No exception, just get nothing back.
>>> cleaned_data.get('foo', "Sane Default")
'Sane Default'
```

Comment: In the context of Django forms, that last line of code implies you can supply a default value for a form field that way. But unless I'm missing something, that doesn't work, at least not in Django 1.8. An optional (`required=False`) form field contains the empty string `''` if not set by the client.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I can see why that may be confusing.  I included it because my answer was more focussed on `cleaned_data` being "Just a Dictionary".  However, if you have an optional field, the entry in the dictionary will exist and `get()` will not use the "Sane Default".  If, however, you have a field that may or may not *exist* then the entry in the dictionary may or may not exist.  Thus requiring caution and, in my case, using `get()` to not throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

cleaned_data is a Python dictionary, you can access its values by:

Specifying the key between [ ]:

```
 self.cleaned_data[‘field’]
```

Using get() method:

```
self.cleaned_data.get(‘field’)
```

Difference between cleaned_data and cleaned_data.get in Django is that if the key does not exist in the dictionary, `self.cleaned_data[‘field’]` will raise a **KeyError**, while `self.cleaned_data.get(‘field’)` will return **None**.