# Django Validate Date & Time in Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a view where I validate date and time on form submit making sure the date + time are not past. Date and Time are two separate fields. It works, but I know its wrong way of doing it and the date+time should be validated in Django Forms.

This is in my `view.py`

(Probably not done the right way but it works)

```
my_date = request.session['reservationdate'] #in "mm/dd/yyyy" format
my_time = request.session['reservationtime'] #in "hh:mm" format
my_date_time = (my_date + ' ' + my_time + ':00') #convert to "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
my_date_time = datetime.strptime(my_date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') #convert to valid datetime
if datetime.now() <= my_date_time:
    #do this
else:
     ...
```

now my goal is to have something like the above in Django forms:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['my_date'].required = True
        self.fields['my_time'].required = True
        ...

    def clean_my_date(self):
        my_date = self.cleaned_data['my_date']
        my_time = self.cleaned_data['my_time']
        my_date_time = (my_date + ' ' + my_time + ':00')
        my_date_time = datetime.strptime(my_date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        if datetime.now() <= my_date_time:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Wrong Date!')
        return my_date

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_date', 'my_time', ...]
```

**Edit:**

**working code:**

```
def clean_my_time(self):
   my_date = self.cleaned_data['my_date']
   my_time = self.cleaned_data['my_time']
   my_date_time = ('%s %s' % (my_date, my_time))
   my_date_time = datetime.strptime(my_date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
   if datetime.now() >= my_date_time:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Wrong Date or Time! "%s"' % my_date_time)
   return my_time
```

Thanks to all for the help especially **xyres** for his work and for being patient with me!

Comment: There's actually no need to define `__init__` method in your forms. But where is the problem?

Comment: Its a `KeyError`. its complaining about the `my_time = self.cleaned_data['my_time']`

Comment: Try using `my_time = self.cleaned_data.get('my_time')`.

Comment: Thanks. It is accept that however now the next line is returning this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'`

Comment: I understand but it is all that is in the traceback: 'TypeError at /url/url/ ... unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str''. APparently the use of the `+` is not allowed in forms. Any other way how to combine two fields in forms?

Comment: Well, you could use `my_date_time = ('%s %s:00' % (my_date, my_time))`.

Comment: But that is not the actual problem. When you were using `cleaned_data['my_time']`, you were getting `KeyError` because there is no field named `my_time` in your form. When you used `cleaned_data.get(...)` `KeyError` is not raise, because `get()` method returns an empty string when field is not there.

Comment: You are correct, the `my_time' is returning 'NONE'. So the question is how can I used the 'my_time' value that is being passed from the form?

Comment: Is there a field for `my_time` in your HTML template? When you visit the page can you see the field? Can you see `<input name="my_time" ... >` in that page's source code? That is all I can say without looking at your templates.

Comment: As you can see from my OP the `my_time` field is there and is being correctly validated by the Djano Forms. Are you sure the value `self.cleaned_data['my_time']` is OK to use in there?

Comment: Yes, if you know for sure that the field is there in the form, then there should be no problem with `self.cleaned_data['my_time']`. And yes I'm sure because I've seen it in docs. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592552/difference-between-cleaned-data-and-cleaned-data-get-in-django).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to answer one last time. Instead of doing `def clean_my_date(...)`, do this:

```
def clean_my_time(self):
    # rest of your code remains same
```

If the above solution doesn't work, [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497497/django-self-cleaned-data-keyerror#answer-21497552).

**Update**

Since the above code worked, I feel I should try and explain why and how.

Let's look at the order of fields in your form

```
fields = ['my_date', 'my_time', ...]
```

As, you can see `my_time` field comes *after* `my_date` field. So, when your code was like

```
def clean_my_date(self)
```

the `clean()` method of your form gets called and it returns a dictionary object called `cleaned_data`. This `cleaned_data` dict has all the keys *i.e.* fields of your form **upto** `my_date` field. Any field that is after `my_date` won't be in `cleaned_data`.  As, `my_time` field is after `my_date` field, it was not in `cleaned_data`. That is why you got a `KeyError`.

After changing your code to

```
def clean_my_time(self)
```

the `clean()` method returned `cleaned_data` with all the fields **upto** `my_time`. As `my_date` comes before `my_time`, it is, therefore, present in `cleaned_data`. Hence, no error.

So it depends on the order of your form fields. If you want to validate two fields together, do it in the `clean_my_field(self)` method of the field that comes later in order. The answer posted by *Jérôme Thiard* is also a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and your patience! With little tweaking I was able to solve it. Working code in my OP. Thanks again!

Comment: @WayBehind I'm glad I was able to help. :)

Comment: @WayBehind In case you run into the same problem again, I've updated my answer with some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I didnt realize the Django form would not receive all data from the online form. I'm still fairly new to Django and Python as I came from many years of ColdFusion coding where things works just in different way and CF is not as sensitive to a "dirty" code. Thanks again! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to validate over multiple fields. This point is well covered by the django documentation, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other.

The job has to be done in the `clean` method.
Assuming django 1.7, your code could look like

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['my_date'].required = True
        self.fields['my_time'].required = True
        ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        # here all fields have been validated individually,
        # and so cleaned_data is fully populated
        my_date = cleaned_data.get('my_date')
        my_time = cleaned_data.get('my_time')
        if my_date and my_time:
            my_date_time = (my_date + ' ' + my_time + ':00')
            my_date_time = datetime.strptime(my_date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
            if datetime.now() <= my_date_time:
                msg = u"Wrong Date time !"
                self.add_error('my_date', msg)
                self.add_error('my_time', msg)
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_date', 'my_time', ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It returned the same error as my OP. I think with a little tweaking your code would work too!